# Android Overflow icon on tool bar/app bar is not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am trying to make the `Overflow icon` visible. But for some reason, most of the times it remains invisible.

Since my emulator hasn't been working for sometime, I have been using my phone for previews. My phone supports `SDK 17`. My `minSDK` set for the project is 17.

The toolbar and Title gets displayed normally. However, the 'Overflow icon' and hence the `'actions'` always goes missing. Does it has something to do with my phone's app version? (probably not because, the overflow icon and the actions are visible sometimes when beginning with new project)

I have gone through various resources, yet unable to identify the problem/the reason. I am posting the Toolbar image for reference. Could someone please assist me?

Regards

***Update:***
Here goes the link to the image

[image]

I do have the haptic (not sure if it's capacitve/resistive) touch buttons. Have tried, but in vain.

Also, my Android Studio is up-to-date

Here goes the code

============activity_main.xml===============

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <!-- Tool bar/App bar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <!-- Home Screen list -->
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <!-- Search bar -->


</RelativeLayout>
```

=============mainactivity.java===============

```
package com.example.bharathduraiswamy.pointofsale;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"};
    ListView dailyList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // Sets a toolbar to replace the action bar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        dailyList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> template = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, days);
        dailyList.setAdapter(template);
        dailyList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView temp = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(this, temp.getText() + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Does your device have a MENU button? If yes, have you tried pressing the MENU button? "Unfortunately I am not able to post a pic as I don't hold the necessary reputation" -- feel free to upload it elsewhere and link to it from your question.

Comment: "the overflow icon and the actions are visible sometimes when beginning with new project", that makes pinpointing the actual problem so much harder..

Answer (score 1):

The overflow icon is shown only on devices lacking hardware menu button. On devices with it, the overflow menu is accessed using this button.